# JS new Image() or document.createElement("img") - image is there but not visible

Tags: javascript, image, createelement

I have a strange issue. I have a JS function that creates a  and inside this div i create a new image element. this function i call with

```
document.body.onload = buildCopy;
```

So everything works perfectly while testing on a file. But when i moved the script to an actual site hosted on a web server the image doesn't show. It is there - it is on the DOM, i can actually drag it and then it becomes visible while being dragged but the image does not seem to redner properly on its own.

I've tried using both new Image() and createElement('img') but it is the same.

Here is the function of creating the image (copyDivs is a another element with a class of "c0py"):

```
// create the div that will encompass the entire clipboard image + tooltip
const createTooltipDiv = document.createElement('div');
// add class tooltip
createTooltipDiv.classList.add('tooltip');
// insert it right after the c0py element
copyDivs[i].parentNode.insertBefore(createTooltipDiv, copyDivs[i].nextSibling);
// save the tooltip div to a variable for later use
const tooltipDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip')[i];
// Let's create the clipboard image
const clipboardImg = document.createElement("img");
// Add the c0py-icon class which serves purpose for the onclick event later
clipboardImg.classList.add('c0py-icon');
clipboardImg.src = '/images/Clipboard.svg';
clipboardImg.alt = 'Copy this reference to Clipboard';
// Add it as a child of the tooltip div
tooltipDiv.appendChild(clipboardImg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it turned out that another .css or .js have intererred with the .tooltip CSS class. I learnt this by trying out the code on a blank page, then i added more external/internal css files and other scripts and slowly got to the bottom of it. So if you run into the same problem, check out competing css/js files. Too bad there is not a single error/crossed css property in F12 Dev tools.